# PHP parse_ini_file with slashes in WINDOWS PHP 5.3.0

Tags: php, ini, dokuwiki

I am using the wiki software: dokuwiki and since installing the template: http://www.dokuwiki.org/template:monobook

I have been getting this error when testing locally using WAMP on windows 7 64bit:
Apache: 2.2.11
PHP: 5.3.0

**UPDATE** I have upgraded my PHP version to 5.3.1 and this has fixed the errors.

> **Warning**:  parse error in
>   C:\wamp\www\wiki\lib\exe/../../lib/tpl/monobook/style.ini on line 30 
>   in **C:\wamp\www\wiki\lib\exe\css.php** on line **54**
>   **Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   **C:\wamp\www\wiki\lib\exe\css.php** on line **55**

*style.ini*

```
; INI to handle loading of the CSS files of the "monobook" template for DokuWiki
;
;
; LICENSE: This file is open source software (OSS) and may be copied under
;          certain conditions. See COPYING file for details or try to contact
;          the author(s) of this file in doubt.
;
; @license GPLv2 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl2.html)
; @author Andreas Haerter <development@andreas-haerter.com>
; @link http://andreas-haerter.com/projects/dokuwiki-template-monobook
; @link http://www.dokuwiki.org/template:monobook
; @link http://www.dokuwiki.org/devel:css#styleini



; Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php
; for limitations of the ini format used here

; Define the stylesheets your template uses here. The second value
; defines for which output media the style should be loaded. Currently
; print, screen and rtl are supported. rtl styles are loaded additionally
; to screen styles if a right-to-left language is selected (eg. hebrew)
[stylesheets]

; screen
; note to myself: don't forget to respect the workaround within "bug49642.php"
;                 when adding new screen styles.
; load the DokuWiki styles. See <http://j.mp/eq8zSo> why I am doing this.
[line:30] static/3rd/dokuwiki/_imgdetail.css        = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_media_popup.css      = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_media_fullscreen.css = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_fileuploader.css     = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_tabs.css             = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_links.css            = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_toc.css              = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_footnotes.css        = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_search.css           = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_recent.css           = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_diff.css             = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_edit.css             = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_modal.css            = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_forms.css            = screen
static/3rd/dokuwiki/_admin.css            = screen

; load the most important MediaWiki monobook styles
static/3rd/monobook/main.css = screen

; load the specific "monobook for dokuwiki" styles
static/css/screen.css = screen
user/screen.css       = screen
```

This is the PHP code in css.php which loads the ini file:

```
// load template styles
$tplstyles = array();
if(@file_exists($tplinc.'style.ini')){
    $ini = parse_ini_file($tplinc.'style.ini',true);
    foreach($ini['stylesheets'] as $file => $mode){
        $tplstyles[$mode][$tplinc.$file] = $tpldir;
    }
}
```

Comment: The above file parses OK for me using PHP/5.2.17-win32 (once the `[line:30]` has been removed from what is actually line 29 in my editor). Slashes are not AFAIK special characters in ini files and should be legal in the keys. Is this a simple ISO-8859-1 file? No UTF messing you around?

Comment: PHP 5.3 is parsing this file with no probs (on a mac)

Comment: Yes both correct, I have just tested on a Linux server and it is working correctly. It must have been a issue with the PHP version because once I upgraded to 5.3.1 the errors went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a known bug in PHP 5.3.0 only. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49692